# ModuleNotFoundError. Pycharm

Tags: python, библиотеки, pycharm

Подключаю модуль pyqtgraph

Получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/kurov/lesson_4/graphic.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyqtgraph as pg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph
```

Работаю в pycharm. Скачал и установил библиотеку по инструкции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136101/discussion-on-question-by-garin-modulenotfounderror-pycharm).

Answer (score 1):

У тебя разные интерпретаторы используются для запуска скрипта и в настройках IDE:

[image: разные интерпретаторы]

Скорее всего для соответствующей Run Configuration (**Run | Edit Configurations ...**) выбран интерпретатор отличный от проектного:

[image: интерпретатор в ран конфигурации]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить модуль, открыв терминал снизу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И прописать в нём `pip install pyqtgraph`